# La 3e personne du singulier ou du pluriel après un démonstratif ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, accord, démonstratifs

Une question me turlupine lorsque que je prends mes cours dit-on :
"Cette chose est les papiers" ou "Cette chose sont les papiers" ?

Excusez-moi pour l'exemple réductif. 
Sachant, que "chose" est au singulier, et qu'on donne une définition de ce mot qui est au singulier, doit-on quand même mettre la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel ensuite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question toujours délicate.

#### Singulier ou pluriel

« Cette chose » est le sujet du verbe. Le verbe s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec son sujet. Le sujet est singulier. **Le verbe est donc au singulier.**

Nous sommes toutefois d'accord sur le déséquilibre produit par un sujet au singulier qualifiant un objet pluriel.

Pour limiter ce malaise, il y a une solution.

#### La reformulation

Pour s'éviter ce genre de problèmes, on peut essayer de tourner sa phrase autrement. Par exemple :

> Ce sont les papiers…

Pour conserver l'aspect démonstratif (« je pointe du doigt »), on peut renforcer ainsi :

> Ça, ce sont les papiers…

Ou en réponse à « Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette chose ? », on pourra répondre :

> Cette chose, ce sont les papiers…<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Si cette phrase ne me choque pas, je ne suis pas certain de sa correction au niveau grammatical : « ce » est censé reprendre « cette chose ». Il devrait donc être singulier mais est utilisé au pluriel. Ce genre de tournure démonstrative est cependant typiquement orale, contexte dans lequel des libertés bien plus choquantes sont prises avec la langue de Molière.</sub>

Comment: Il y aussi la possibilité d'ajouter un `?` en reprinant l'interrogation dans la réponse : "Cette chose ? ... des papiers !".

Comment: Ce serait une tournure correcte à l'oral et non à l'écrit? Il conviendrait dans tous les cas de mettre le pluriel.
Pour donner un autre exemple la vrai tournure serait plus celle-ci " Le deuxième principe représente les répartitions des dépenses", mon professeur aurait tendance à dire : "le deuxième principe sont les répartitions des dépenses". Ainsi pourquoi cela changerait pour le verbe être?

Ps: Je vous remercie de l'attention portée à ma demande

Comment: Il y a une différence fondamentale entre « représenter » et « être » : un porte-parole peut _représenter_ un groupe, une pluralité, mais il ne peut pas _être_ un groupe. Dans le premier cas, on a un complément d'objet direct ; dans le second, ainsi que [justement souligné par GAM PUB](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16053/7224), cela devient un attribut du sujet. Le problème vient du fait que l'attribut est normalement accordé avec le sujet, ce qui n'est pas le cas dans votre exemple.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux propositions présentent le même goût "étranger". Ni le singulier, ni le pluriel ne semblent donner une formulation "correcte".

Dans cet [usage du verbe ÊTRE](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copule_%28linguistique%29), le verbe s'accorde en personne avec le sujet, mais il y a aussi accord en genre et en nombre de l'attribut avec le sujet.

> Cette chose est originale
>   ?Cette chose est originaux?

Dans les cas présentés, il n'y a aucun moyen de respecter le deuxième accord (sujet singulier vs attribut pluriel).

Comme proposé par @Chop, la reformulation semble inévitable. Le pronom sujet *ce*, qui ne fonctionne qu'avec ce type d'usage, a le mérite de ne pas marquer le nombre. Dans l'usage avec les attributs nominaux, on trouve des accords avec les deux personnes : 3SG et 3PL.

> Qui crie ? C'est les enfants.
>   Qui crie ? Ce sont les enfants.

Toutefois ce choix semble disparaître pour les attributs adjectivaux :

> C'est génial !
>   *Ce sont géniaux !

Comment: Dans la nomenclature classique, *les papiers* est l'attribut du sujet dans la phrase initiale.

Comment: Wikipédia : [Attribut](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_%28grammaire%29)

Comment: SOS grammaire (pas en tant que référence, mais avec l'avantage de quelques exemples) : [Attribut du sujet, GN](http://sosgrammaire.voila.net/attsujet.html). Merci de m'avoir corrigé.

Answer (score 0):

Selon moi la formulation correct serait :

> "Ces choses sont des papiers"

Il existe des démonstratifs pluriels, autant les utiliser.

Comment: Mon exemple n'était pas très bon. Je voulais dire, lorsqu'on donne la définition d'un objet par exemple : Le deuxième principe représente les répartitions des dépenses, mon professeur aurait tendance à dire : le deuxième principe sont les répartitions des dépenses.

Comment: Dans ce cas, il faudrait ajouter un verbe. "Le deuxième principe {regroupe, inclue, comprend, etc. } les répartitions des dépenses"